# Move letter in word n-times

Tags: c++

I have to do a program that take sentence and move n-times every letter in every word, but I need from some help about it. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string trimSpaces(string trimStr)
{
    while (trimStr[0] == ' ')
    {
        trimStr.erase(0, 1);
    }
    return trimStr;
}

string getWord(string &sentence)
{
    sentence = trimSpaces(sentence);
    int i = 0;
    while (sentence[i] != ' ' && i < sentence.size())
    {
        i++;
    }
    string word = sentence.substr(0, i);
    sentence.erase(0, i);

    return word;
}

string transformWord(string word, int n)
{
    //char* resultWord = new char[word.length()]();
    string resultWord;
    string helpingWord;
    char firstSymbol = word[0];
    char secondSymbol = word[1];
    char preLastSymbol = word[word.length() - 2];
    char lastSymbol = word[word.length() - 1];
    bool fl = false;
    bool fl2 = false;
    bool fl3 = false;

    if (firstSymbol == '"')
    {
        fl2 = true;
        firstSymbol = word[1];
        secondSymbol = word[2];
    }

    if (lastSymbol == '.' || lastSymbol == '"' || lastSymbol == ',' || (preLastSymbol == '.' && lastSymbol == '"'))
    {
        if (preLastSymbol == '.' && lastSymbol == '"')
        {
            fl = true;
            word.erase(word.length() - 3, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            fl3 = true;
            word.erase(word.length() - 2, 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        resultWord += word[(i + n % word.length()) % word.length()];
    }

    helpingWord = resultWord;

    if (fl)
    {
        helpingWord += (preLastSymbol + lastSymbol);
    }
    if (fl2)
    {
        helpingWord = word[0] + helpingWord;
    }
    if (fl3)
    {
        helpingWord += lastSymbol;
    }
    return helpingWord;
}

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    string resultSentence;
    int n;

    getline(cin, sentence);

    cin >> n;

    while (sentence.size() > 0)
    {
        string word = getWord(sentence);
        word = transformWord(word, n);
        resultSentence += word;
    }

    cout << resultSentence << '\n';
}
```

I think that the problem comes from here

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        resultWord += word[(i + n % word.length()) % word.length()];
    }
```

when I add the letters of the `word` to `resultWord`
If we input: `Pesho 3` the output must me: `shoPe`, but my output is `hoPes`;
And if we enter sentence like:

```
Oh, what fun it is to
ride in a one horse open sleigh.
```

The result must be: `hO, hatw fun ti si ot ider ni a one rseho peno ighsle.`

Comment: What, _exactly_, is your problem? What sort of _help_ do you need?

Comment: split the string into words, `std::rotate` each word, and then stitch it all back together.

Comment: You can even rotate in the original string (or its copy), as std::rotate operates on iterators (so it can rotate just a part of the string).

Comment: @axalis In the OP's example the words to not change position.  doing `rotate` on the whole string would change the word position.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't say to rotate the entire string, just to rotate the words directly in it, using iterators. I.e. to not split the entire string into particular words (as separate strings).

Comment: If someone can give me some code will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The brutal and stupid way to do it. This isn't super fast or efficient, but it is really, really easy to write and read. Rule of thumb is to, (Paraphrasing Einstein here) make everything as simple as possible, but no simpler. If this isn't fast enough, plenty of time to tweak it later. But if you uselessly tweak it now, you could be wasting valuable time on optimizing something that doesn't need to be faster.

Caveats:

This is punctuation blind but I've inserted notes on where you could handle the punctuation. The simple hack is: While the last character is punctuation, move it to a stack. Rotate remainder of string, then pop off the stack onto the end of the rotated string.

Now onto the rotate!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // hard coding the input for ease of test
    std::string sentence = "Oh, what fun it is to\nride in a one horse open sleigh. ";
    std::stringstream resultSentence;

    //    getline(cin, sentence); don't need this for test. Hard-coded the input

    // put sentence in stream for easy parsing
    std::stringstream stream(sentence); 
    std::string word;

    // chop stream into words. Note this is punctuation-blind. You will have 
    // to be a bit smarter.
    while (stream >> word) 
    {
        // shift left one character
        // trim and store trailing punctuation here
        std::rotate(word.begin(), word.begin()+1, word.end());

        // add to output. Note the redundant space that will be added to the end
        // it may become important.
        resultSentence << word << /* add trailing punctuation here */" ";
    }
    // print result.
    std::cout << resultSentence.str() << '\n';
}
```

[`std::stringstream` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

[`std::rotate` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)